# Is there an equivalent of Jquery's animate() and find() in ExtJS?

Tags: extjs

I'm thinking of using ExtJS in one of my latest project. However, I'm struggling on how to reproduce animate() and find() in extJS. I'm still an early user in ExtJS, hence I might missed out some stuffs.

Here's a snippet that I would like to reproduce in ExtJS.

```
$(element)
        .animate({ width: 50 })
        .find("img")
        .animate({ width: 150 })
             .end()
        .find("h1")
        .animate({ fontSize: 20 });
```

Cheers,
Mickey

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in [Ext FX](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.Fx) and Ext Element (http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.Element)

Comment: Cool, thanks. You know if there is any equivalent of children() like $(element).children()

Comment: Simple

element.child('selector');

Comment: I mean all the children. In Jquery, there is .children() which retrieve all the children